# Remove content after . from string

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a string var x = 2019-02-14T21:06:06.400Z

Another string y = 2019-02-14T21:06:06.44500Z

I need to remove content after the dot i cant slice it because the dot might come after 4 or 5 or 6 or n characters

Comment: `.split('.')[0]`  i'm 99% sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Convert your string to a Date object and format it there to exclude what you don't want

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```js
 

let [beforeDot] = "2019-02-14T21:06:06.400Z".split(".");
console.log(beforeDot);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` in conjunction with an array access by index.

Example:

```
"2019-02-14T21:06:06.44500Z".split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.

```js
const strIn = "2019-02-14T21:06:06.44500Z";

const index  = strIn.indexOf(".");

const strOut = strIn.substr(0, index);

console.log(strOut);
```